# Умножить таблицу Excel, R

Tags: excel, r, join

**Нужно объединить две таблицы**
Первая, города и типы оплаты.

> Города ---- Тип оплаты
>   1 Москва   ---- Hight
>   2 Самара  -  Medium
>   3 Казань  -----   low

*И вторая, услуги и стоимость в зависимости от типа оплаты:*

> артикул---  установка -  hight --- medium  --- low
>   010101  ------  мойка   ---    1000 -----  700   -------  500
>   020202 -------   кран    ----    1400  ---- 1000  -------  750
>   *Получиться должна таблица вида:*
>   город ---- артикул -- установка -- стоимость
>   Москва -- 010101 ----- мойка --------  1000 
>   Москва -- 020202 -------кран ----------1400
>   Самара-- 010101-------мойка ----------700
>   Самара-- 020202 -------кран ----------1000
>   ......

Answer (score 1):

```
library(data.table)
towns <- data.table(town=c('Москва','Самара','Казань'), 
                    pay_level= c('Hi','Me','Lo'),
                    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
                    )
servs <- data.table(art=c('010101','020202'),
                    tp=c('Мойка','Кран'),
                    Hi=c(1000,1400),
                    Me=c(700,1000),
                    Lo=c(500, 750),
                    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
                    )
cor_servs <- melt(servs,id.vars = c('art','tp'), 
                  variable.name = 'pay_level', 
                  value.name = 'price')
merge(towns, cor_servs)[,2:5]
```

Answer (score -1):

Сделал так:

`Set wsFrom1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("лист1")
    Set wsFrom2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("лист2")
    Set wsTo = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("лист3")

```
For citys = 2 To 192
 For prices = 4 To 137

    r1 = citys: c1 = 1
    r2 = citys: c2 = 4
    r3 = rowcounter: c3 = 1
    r4 = rowcounter: c4 = 4

    With wsFrom1
       Set CopyFrom = .Range(.Cells(r1, c1), .Cells(r2, c2))
    End With

    With wsTo
        Set CopyTo = .Range(.Cells(r3, c3), .Cells(r4, c4))
    End With
         CopyFrom.Copy CopyTo

    r1 = prices: c1 = 1
    r2 = prices: c2 = 17
    r3 = rowcounter: c3 = 5
    r4 = rowcounter: c4 = 23

    With wsFrom2
       Set CopyFrom = .Range(.Cells(r1, c1), .Cells(r2, c2))
    End With

    With wsTo
        Set CopyTo = .Range(.Cells(r3, c3), .Cells(r4, c4))
    End With
         CopyFrom.Copy CopyTo
    rowcounter = rowcounter + 1
 Next prices
Next citys`
```